# Execute block insert error "Too many context of relation/procedures/views."

Tags: firebird, bulkinsert, firebird2.5

I am trying to implement bulk insert into my Firebird database using block insertion.

Syntax is as follows:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK AS
BEGIN
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (F_1, F_2) VALUES  ('1', NULL) ;
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (F_1, F_2) VALUES  ('2', '01.01.2016') ;
...
...
END
```

Of course, queries are a bit more complex with way more fields, but well, point is, I run into the following error message:

**"Too many context of relation/procedures/views. Maximum allowed is 255"**

when the number of queries is somewhere above 80. I really don't know the relation between the shown `255` and my queries.

Any help?

**UPDATE**
Some relevant DDL information:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
  F_1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  F_2 TIMESTAMP,
  F_3 INTEGER,
  LAST_UPDATE TIMESTAMP
 CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (F_1)
);

ALTER TABLE F_1 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MY_TABLE_F_3_SOME_OTHER
  FOREIGN KEY (F_3) REFERENCES SOME_OTHER
  (SOME_OTHER_PK_ID) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
;   

CREATE ASC INDEX I_MY_TABLE_F1 ON MY_TABLE (F1);

CREATE DESC INDEX I_MY_TABLE_LAST_UPDATE ON MY_TABLE (LAST_UPDATE);

SET TERM ^^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER MY_TABLE_BIU FOR MY_TABLE ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE POSITION 0 AS
begin  
  if (new.F1 is null) then  
  begin  
    new.F1 = gen_id( GEN_MY_TABLE_F1, 1 );  
  end
  new.LAST_UPDATE = current_timestamp;
end ^^
SET TERM ; ^^
```

Note that I have several FKs, up to 10, and as said, way more fields.

Comment: Impossible to tell, does the table have one or more triggers (and do those triggers maybe use a stored procedure or another table), is `my_table` an actual table, or is it a view with an instead of trigger, etc, etc. You either need to post all relevant DDL, or you just need to reduce the number of statements in the block.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I disabled indexes and FK, which allowed me to increase the size a little bit, but still not tremendously... I have to keep the triggers to make sure the PK value is set according to the generator... So I went from 80 to 150 or so...

Comment: I'm afraid there is not much that can be done, except petition the Firebird core developers to increase this limit (which afaik has a lot of technical complexity due to the historical reasons of this limit).